# How to replace words in string and ignore numbers in string

Tags: javascript, regex

What i'm trying to achieve is searching value in array if it matches specific variable, then replace it with other variable (which is translation for this word), array value consist number and i need only to translate words without touching the number. Here is an example.

```
var arr = ["18 pages"];
var item = "18 pages";
var translate = "pagina's";

if(arr.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/[^0-9 ]/, translate);
    alert(arr);
}
```

Output is: `18 pagina'sages`

Expected output: 18 pagina's

So it needs only to translate words and keep numbers.

How can i do it properly?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: expected output: 18 pagina's

Comment: `[^0-9 ]` means *"one character that isn't a digit or a space"*. `[^0-9 ]+` means *"one or more characters that aren't digits or spaces"*. `+` is called a quantifier (information available in all tutorials about regex, read one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility for solving this problem would be to find multiple characters surrounded by boundaries and replace these. This would be the regular expression: `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b`. Here is an executable example:

```js
let arr = ["18 pages"];
let item = "18 pages";
let translate = "pagina's";

if (arr.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
  arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/, translate);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

If you run this snippet you will get the expected output: `18 pagina's`.

**Update:**

Another alternative which would first match a character and then match any characters excluding numbers (`[a-zA-Z][^0-9]+`) would be able to replace more complex expressions and not just a single word.

Here is a running example based on the fiddle in https://jsfiddle.net/9uta5bo4/2/:

```js
let arr = "18 pagina’s per minuut";
let item = "pagina’s per minuut";
let translate = "pages par minute";

if (arr.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
  arr = arr.replace(/[a-zA-Z][^0-9]+/, translate);
  console.log(arr);
}
```

If you run this fiddle you will see the output:

```
18 pages par minute
```

Another alternative to `[a-zA-Z][^0-9]+` is `[^0-9 ][^0-9]+` which finds any character which is not a number or space first and then anything which is not a number multiple times.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i make it appear with the space after number, i put space inside [0-9 ] but getting this output, here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/9uta5bo4/2/

Comment: @Andrew Please see my updated answer. Let me know if is what you want.

Comment: Thank You! Exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You're only matching a single character with `[^0-9 ]`. I suspect you want `[^0-9 ]+`.

Comment: PS: The Spanish for "pages" is simply "paginas", without any apostrophe.

Comment: thanks worked, but for example if i have longer value with several spaces it remove space between number and first words like this 18pages and if i use space after number [0-9 ] its getting messy again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ["18 pages"];
let item = "18 pages";
let translate = "pagina's";
if (arr.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
  var res = arr[0].replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/g, translate); //replace only letters
  var res2 = arr[0].replace(/[^0-9|\s]+/g, translate); // ecxlcude numbers and space 
  var res3 = arr[0].replace(/[^\d|\s]+/, translate); // ecxlcude numbers and space 
  console.log(res);
  console.log(res2);
  console.log(res3);

}
```